# How to set constraints for IBOutlet programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I tried for much time to set position of UIButton using constraints programmatically and googled the same. But couldn’t get it. If I take the button programmatically, it’s working fine.

Here button is taken as IBOutlet in storyboard.

Here’s my code

```
[btnBack setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSDictionary *dictViews = @{@"btnBack" : btnBack};

NSArray *arr_WIDTH_btnBack = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnBack(46)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:dictViews];
NSArray *arr_HEIGHT_btnBack = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[btnBack(30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:dictViews];
[btnBack addConstraints:arr_WIDTH_btnBack];
[btnBack addConstraints:arr_HEIGHT_btnBack];

NSArray *arr_POS_btnBack_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[btnBack]" options:0 metrics:nil views:dictViews];
NSArray *arr_POS_btnBack_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-31-[btnBack]" options:0 metrics:nil views:dictViews];
[self.view addConstraints:arr_POS_btnBack_H];
[self.view addConstraints:arr_POS_btnBack_V];
```

Am getting error -

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|-16-[btnBack]

I don’t know where I did mistake. Did I miss anything?

TIA

Comment: Why you set UIButton in storyboard and constraints programmatically? Is's so easy to set constraints in storyboard.

Comment: Excuse my silly answer 

Comment: I have been practicing Auto layouts for a day. I am practicing and trying to explore in all the ways. I have learnt to set constraints separately in storyboard and programmatically. But I am stuck at setting constraints programmatically for IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

did you put the code above in viewDidLoad? I have a similiar problem. In viewdidload, all the views in the storyboard have yet to be added to the UIViewController's view. You can do a quick NSLog of the `self.subviews` and you will not see UIButton there.

Only by in the cycle of viewDidAppear than it will be added. If you add your constraints in viewDidAppear, it should work.

however, the problem is that the constraints will appear only after loading the view.